# Why doesn't anything happen when I connect my Nexus S to a MacBook Pro 2010 using a USB cable?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb

I've tried to connect a Nexus S to a MBP 2010 via USB. After connection, the Mac does not respond.

Anybody know why? I have tried it with a powered USB hub and get the same result: No responses for the USB storage.

Comment: What do you mean by "not any responses"? Which response do you expect?

Comment: What are you using from your Nexus-S? The USB Storage? The Internet Connection?

Answer (score 3):

Fire up system profiler on your mac. This can be refreshed to show all USB devices connected - even if there is a driver issue, at least you'll know if the cable and physical connection are good.

Answer (score 3):

And finally I have found this issue is caused by a bad USB cable.

It is working when I use a HTC USB cable to connect to my MBP.

Answer (score -1):

You may need to download software provided by Samsung to connect your device by USB.

Comment: The Samsung Nexus-S doesn't need any software and should appear as a regular USB storage where you can copy/move music, pictures and videos.